# Displaying an IFrame over an Applet? Bad idea?

Tags: java, html, iframe, applet

In code I am working with there are instances where an IFrame gets placed partially over a Java Applet. I thought this approach was a "hack" and wasn't guaranteed to work correctly across browsers but up until now there hasn't been any show stopping bugs with the approach... Today however I found circumstances where on firefox 3.6 the applet always stays on top of the IFrame, breaking the feature.

Should we be displaying an IFrame over an Applet or is that a bad idea?

Thanks!

Comment: could you let us know the reason why the iframe placed over the applet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a hack but it is not necessarily a bad idea. Of course it's best if the page can be redesigned to avoid the necessity of this hack but that is not always the case*.

This is a fairly well supported hack that have been extensively tested by many people on many different browsers. If what you're saying is true then it appears that this hack is no longer as reliable as it used to be.

*note: it is not always possible to convince your boss/client to not use Java/Flash/Silverlight or to break the designer's vision of how the page should work.